# Apache start error -

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

Getting following error while starting the Apache. Tried all possible things found on Stackoverflow or google -

```
[Thu Jun 14 05:03:22.973799 2018] [ssl:trace2] [pid 13154] ssl_engine_rand.c(126): Init: Seeding PRNG with 144 bytes of entropy
[Thu Jun 14 05:03:22.973834 2018] [ssl:info] [pid 13154] AH01887: Init: Initializing (virtual) servers for SSL
[Thu Jun 14 05:03:22.973840 2018] [ssl:info] [pid 13154] AH01876: mod_ssl/2.4.25 compiled against Server: Apache/2.4.25, Library: OpenSSL/1.0.2h
[Thu Jun 14 05:03:22.973858 2018] [http2:debug] [pid 13154] mod_http2.c(103): AH03089: initializing post config dry run
[Thu Jun 14 05:03:22.974292 2018] [core:emerg] [pid 13154] (22)Invalid argument: AH00024: Couldn't set permissions on the rewrite-map mutex; check User and Group directives
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

Comment: Could you post your relevant SSL config ?